# Reading document's sub-field in mongoose that does not have a sub-field property returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My collection Test schema is nested like:

```
Test: {
    name: String,
    subField: {
        name: String,
        ref: {type: ObjectId, ref: "Test"}
    }
}
```

I do a find like:

```
dbs.Test.find({})exec().then(function(collection){ ...
```

It returns all the documents. Then I access a field that has a name, but no subField name.

```
var field = collection[0];
field.name // returns name
field.subField // console.log is an empty object
```

It returns an empty object in the console. I assumed it would be null/undefined. What is field.subField actually returning if it does not have a subField name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)  method of mongoose to fetch the referenced field.

```
dbs.Test.find({}).populate('subField').exec().then(function(collection){ ...
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you know what it returns if I don't populate? Does it still have  the name and ref?

Comment: Nope, it should not be. I personally use { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Test' } in the schema and it stores ObjectId of that Test document. So, it returns the only objectId. Read carefully the documentation. If you wanna make type number or string, referenced schema unique key must be the same type.